# How to maintain a Max-length string list, remove the first when new string comes in

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, list

I would like to maintain a list of strings with max-length.

For example, if I want to maintain a list with max-length 3. I want to push to the list if length <3, and if length reaches 3 when I'm pushing, I want to remove the first entry.

```
const list = ["A", "B", "C"]
list.push("D")
// Logic

// I want to see ["B","C","D"]
console.log(list)
```

Any Ideas to achieve this?

Comment: Using just `push` is impossible, you should create a function that performs `shift` and `push` in sequence. Anyway it's not about TypeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class to set you rule of max length:

```
class MaxLengthArray {

    private _array: string[];

    get array() {
        return this._array;
    }

    constructor() {
        this._array = [];
    }

    public insert(newValue: string) {
        if (this.array.length >= 3) {
            this.array.push(newValue);
            this.array.shift();
        } else {
            this.array.push(newValue);
        }
    }

}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyYA8AyBTAdgcwC4AsCCATgWAJ7QDeAUJdLdAA4ECWAbmFitAPphGkBc0CFmaYA2gF0A3NTrQMKLNF7ESACgCUFGnLoFFAVwJpouJhAB0PPiRlyAvrLrAA9mmEEDwLC4KbtunRmltaq0AC80JJ2dI46tPQGAEYgTMDQTO4oBFhqaCgA7gBqYCAGKIIemRhaVIG0TABm0GrBFiqkFiDo2DjQAHyRAMy18fW0bR0kFokQOHmFJWUoGjHjEzjm7TYWc025q2MO0CggEJx16xtbUzMGcwvFpeWH444O1HGu7koIEdD5ApwRCoTC4QiqTQySgICyZc45NQAcjwSMOsPh2VySIAQmiZBisoikQBhfEwuFE7EAEXJlG+EBc3S6LgwalhUw0QA

Answer (score 2):

`shift` will remove the element from beginning and then use `push` to add the element.

```
let list = ["A", "B", "C"]
list.length < 3 ? list.push("D"): modifyArr(list);

function modifyArr(list){
 list.shift();
 list.push('D');
}
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

What we need is a **Queue**(a bit modified) ,a *first in first out (FIFO)* data structure.

```
class Queue<T> {
  _store: T[] = [];
  push(val: T) {
    if (this._store.length < 3) {
      this._store.push(val);
    } else {
      this._store.shift();
      this._store.push(val);
    }
  }

  GetQ() {
    return this._store;
  }

}
```

NOTE:- The above class *encapsulate* the Queue. You might have to tweak it as per to your needs.